# python matplotlib how do i plot a histrogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I don't really understand how to plot a histogram and I have faced an issues in my assignment. I am trying to plot 2 histograms to show the frequency count of the different fuel types used by each mode. The other histogram will be the frequency count of the different fuels types used by each specific modes, such as taxi.

This is the dataset I am using: https://data.gov.sg/dataset/monthly-motor-vehicle-population-by-type-of-fuel-used

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

title = "motor-vehicle-population-statistics-by-type-of-fuel-used."     
titlelen = len(title)
print("{:*^{titlelen}}".format(title, titlelen=titlelen+6))
print()
data = np.genfromtxt("data/motor-vehicle-population-statistics-by-type-of-fuel-used.csv",
                      dtype=("datetime64[Y]","U100","U110",int),
                      delimiter=",",
                      names=True)

years = np.unique(data["month"])
category = np.unique(data['category'])
type = np.unique(data['type'])
number = data["number"]



cars = data[data["category"]=="Cars"]
carspetrol = cars[cars["type"]=="Petrol"]["number"]
carsCNG = cars[cars["type"]=="CNG"]["number"]
carsDiesel_Electric = cars[cars["type"]=="Diesel-Electric"]["number"]
carsElectric = cars[cars["type"]=="Electric"]["number"]
carsPetrol_CNG = cars[cars["type"]=="Petrol-CNG"]["number"]
carsPetrol_Electric = cars[cars["type"]=="Petrol-Electric"]["number"]
carsPetrolElectricPlug_In = cars[cars["type"]=="Petrol-Electric (Plug-In)"]["number"]

taxis = data[data["category"]=="Taxis"]
Taxispetrol = taxis[taxis["type"]=="Petrol"]["number"]
TaxisCNG = taxis[taxis["type"]=="CNG"]["number"]
TaxisDiesel_Electric = taxis[taxis["type"]=="Diesel-Electric"]["number"]
TaxisElectric = taxis[taxis["type"]=="Electric"]["number"]
TaxisPetrol_CNG = taxis[taxis["type"]=="Petrol-CNG"]["number"]
TaxisPetrol_Electric = taxis[taxis["type"]=="Petrol-Electric"]["number"]
TaxisPetrolElectricPlug_In = taxis[taxis["type"]=="Petrol-Electric (Plug-In)"]["number"]


#motor cyles only have electric and petrol
motor_cyles = data[data["category"]=="Motor-cycles"]
motor_cyles_petrol = motor_cyles[motor_cyles["type"]=="Petrol"]["number"]
motor_cyles_electric = motor_cyles[motor_cyles["type"]=="Electric"]["number"]


bus = data[data["category"]=="Buses"]
buspetrol = bus[bus["type"]=="Petrol"]["number"]
busCNG = bus[bus["type"]=="CNG"]["number"]
busDiesel_Electric = bus[bus["type"]=="Diesel-Electric"]["number"]
busElectric = bus[bus["type"]=="Electric"]["number"]
busPetrol_CNG = bus[bus["type"]=="Petrol-CNG"]["number"]
busPetrol_Electric = bus[bus["type"]=="Petrol-Electric"]["number"]
busPetrolElectricPlug_In = bus[bus["type"]=="Petrol-Electric (Plug-In)"]["number"]

goodsor = data[data["category"]=="Goods & Other Vehicles"]
goodsorpetrol = goodsor[goodsor["type"]=="Petrol"]["number"]
goodsorCNG = goodsor[goodsor["type"]=="CNG"]["number"]
goodsorDiesel_Electric = goodsor[goodsor["type"]=="Diesel-Electric"]["number"]
goodsorElectric = goodsor[goodsor["type"]=="Electric"]["number"]
goodsorPetrol_CNG = goodsor[goodsor["type"]=="Petrol-CNG"]["number"]
goodsorPetrol_Electric = goodsor[goodsor["type"]=="Petrol-Electric"]["number"]
goodsorPetrolElectricPlug_In = goodsor[goodsor["type"]=="Petrol-Electric (Plug-In)"]["number"]



plt.figure(1) # second figure
plt.hist(buspetrol,  
         alpha=0.5, 
         color=['red'])
plt.title("bus petrol",fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('number of users',fontsize=10)

plt.figure(2) # second figure
plt.hist(busCNG,  
         alpha=0.5, 
         color=['red'])
plt.title("bus CNG",fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('number of users',fontsize=10)

plt.figure(3) # second figure
plt.hist(busDiesel_Electric,  
         alpha=0.5, 
         color=['cyan'])
plt.title("busDiesel_Electric",fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('number of users',fontsize=10)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')

plt.figure(4) # second figure
plt.hist(busCNG,  
         alpha=0.5, 
         color=['red'])
plt.title("bus CNG",fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('number of users',fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understood your question, but I though it can be solved as follows:

```
_, bins, _ = plt.hist(busCNG, bins=50, range=[0,80], alpha=0.5, color='r', density=True)
_ = plt.hist(buspetrol, bins=bins, alpha=0.5, color='b', density=True)
_ = plt.hist(busDiesel_Electric, bins=bins, alpha=0.5, color='g', density=True)
_ = plt.hist(busElectric, bins=bins, alpha=0.5, color='#d8dcd6', density=True)
plt.ylabel('number of users',fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

The histogram is not good, because there are few records for each specific mode x fuel type.

Answer (score -1):

I am able to plot all 4 histograms using your code itself.  Only one thing you missed is " ending in the title variable

> Blockquote`title = "motor-vehicle-population-statistics-by-type-of-fuel-used.
>   "`

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, what you actually want is a bar plot. Playing around with your data for buses:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))

bus_data = [buspetrol, busCNG, busDiesel_Electric, busElectric, busPetrol_Electric, busPetrolElectricPlug_In]
bus_data_count = []

for bd in bus_data:
    print
    if len(bd):  # Doing this because some of the bus arrays are empty
        b = bd[0]   # Data are multidimensional, for different months. I'm only taking the first month here, you can iterate over these as well.
        bus_data_count.append(b)
    else:
        bus_data_count.append(0)  # To count the empty ones

bus_data_labels = ['buspetrol', 'busCNG', 'busDieselElectric', 'busElectric', 'busPetrolElectric', 'busPetrolElectricPlugIn']

x = np.arange(len(bus_data))
plt.bar(x, bus_data_count)
plt.xticks(x, bus_data_labels, rotation='45')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Results in:

[image]

You can run similar functions for every dataset that you want to plot.